# How to make node to ignore json file of the same name as a package?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, package.json

With the following folder structure:

```
mypackage/
    index.js
    package.json
mypackage.json
```

When I run `node mypackage`, node quits without running the program, because of `mypackage.json`. If I rename it to `mypackage.jsonx`, then the program executes as expected.

I really want this file to be named `mypackage.json`, and I want to run program with a package name without specifying path to `index.js`, because I want to use an advantage of [exports](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#exports) and different entrypoints.

I've tried to specify `node ./mypackage` and `node ./mypackage/` and `node mypackage/` - it still "runs" the json.

Answer (score -1):

This might be your answer: https://zellwk.com/blog/ignoring-files-from-npm-package/

If you want to ignore specific files, there's a couple ways to do it (.gitignore/.npmignore). You can also whitelist files that you want to include by adding a `files` property to your package.json file.

Comment: It doesn't affect on how `node` resolves the name to run. Tried to include `mypackage.json` to `.npmrc`, it didn't help.

Comment: The suggestion was to use the .npmignore to make Node ignore the file.
Also, I saw a question you deleted right before I answered it. Here's your answer: //Filter Data
        let dataToFilter = { age:32, gender: 'male', score: 95 },
          filteredData = [];

        filteredData = data.filter((item) => Object.keys(dataToFilter).every(f => item[f] === dataToFilter[f]));

        console.log(filteredData)